# What does the disk that fell on the ground contain?

Tags: chobits

I’ve watched *Chobits* years ago and was curious.

The first episode/chapter tells us about how Hideki found Chii in the dumpster.

According to the [plot description in the Wikipedia article *Chobits*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chobits#Plot) (bold emphasis mine):

> The series centers on the life of Hideki Motosuwa, a held-back student attempting to qualify for university by studying at Seki prep school in Tokyo. Besides a girlfriend, he dreams of having a persocom (パソコン?): an android used as a personal computer, which is expensive. On his way home one evening, he stumbles across a persocom in the form of a beautiful girl with floor-length hair lying against a pile of trash bags, and he carries her home, **not noticing that a disk fell on the ground**. Upon turning her on, she instantly regards Hideki with adoration. The only word the persocom seems capable of saying is "chi" (ちぃ Chii<sup>?</sup>), thus he names her that.

What does the disk contain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The contents of the disc were never mentioned in the anime. However, in the manga, it was mentioned in Chapter 82, Page 23/24:**

> [image]

```
                                       Chapter 82 Page 23
```

> [image]

```
                                       Chapter 82 Page 24
```