# Why didn't the writer reveal the contents of the disk that fell on the ground?

Tags: anime-production, chobits

[As mentioned in this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/28437/what-does-the-disk-that-fell-on-the-ground-contain), I am wondering why the writer or the creator of the anime *Chobits* didn't reveal a crucial thing such as the contents of the disk in question.

[According to this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/28763?noredirect=1), the manga revealed the contents of the disk in the late chapters. Why did they not do so in the anime?

As I am not very familiar with finding writer's or creator's comments on their works, I am having a hard time understanding this.

Any reference linked to the subject matter or facts referring to the creation of this anime is very much appreciated.

Comment: Finding information like that can be very hard for anime. Anime creators for the most part don't seem to spend as much time explaining their work as Western creators.The information that does exist is probably in Japanese.

Comment: @Torisuda hmmm Thank you for explaining this. too bad creators didn't much explain their work ,this is a great anime.Should I put a bounty on this question to attract other users to answer? I don't know if many of our japanese friends are members here. :(

Comment: @Torisuda I'm gonna edit my question so that any information considering the anime creation and production can be accepted as an answer.